# A chapter with subsections and no sections

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Suppose I'm writing a `report` document, where most chapters have sections, with subsections within them; but some chapters (say, an introduction) is shorter than the others - about the same size as a section of a "normal" chapter; and I only want this short-chapter to have subsection-level headings.

If I do this, it either messes up the numbering (e.g. I get 1.0.1, 1.0.2 for these section/subsections) - or I also drop the numbering, in which case these subsections are removed from the table-of-contents and I have to reintroduce them "manually".

Anyway, I was wondering what's the idiomatic way to deal with this scenario, or at least what you have found useful to go about it.

Comment: I guess I would just bite the bullet and promote the subsections to sections in that case.

Comment: @moewe: So, as in the famous quote regarding the US and Vietnam: "Withdraw and declare victory"... well, I guess that's not the worst thing I could do :-)

Comment: It's all about the framing ... But on a more serious note, why do you want to use `\section`-less `\subsection`s, i.e. why did you not want to go for the (for me at least natural) way of using `\section` directly. And if you have answered the *why*, there is still the question of what you expect to see. The answer illustrates that you can suppress the spurious 0, but you end up with an apparent inconsistency: The `\subsection` still produce the same output in terms of fonts etc., but the numbering looks like that of a `\section`.

Comment: @einpoklum Bad idea. Your readers might consider that they had gotten a book with a missing section or however something were not correct. Stick to the structure, please. Usually readers can't come and ask.

Comment: @KeksDose: Ok, so what do I do instead?

Comment: @einpoklum If you have two subsections, promote them to sections. If there is only one, merge it with the chapter heading. I can't tell how to structure a paper, but I really liked the introduction written long ago by Umberto Eco about that. Book was translated into many languages: How to Write a Thesis, Come si fa una tesi di laurea, Wie man eine wissenschaftliche Abschlussarbeit schreibt, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The macro `\thesubsection` controls how subsection numbers are displayed, both in section titles and in cross references. By default, it is (effectively) defined as `\thesection.\arabic{subsection}`, and `\thesection` is defined similarly using `\thechapter`. So it takes the (formatted) number of the current section and adds a period and the value of the `subsection` counter.

You can redefine `\thesubsection` so that it expands to `\thechapter.\arabic{subsection}` instead if the value of the `section` counter is zero. Like this:

```
\documentclass{report}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    \thechapter
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{subsection}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\subsection{A subsection}

\chapter{Second chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{Another subsection}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result:

[image] [image]

Comment: Upon rereading your question I now wonder if I answered it at all. You ask for "the idiomatic way" to deal with this scenario, and I don't really know what that would be.

Comment: If you occasionally do what you've described, then it's a 1-sample of what's idiomatic...

Comment: I can't honestly say that I've ever skipped the section level heading, only that this is how I'd do it.

Comment: (Although I suppose the \ifnum...\fi bit is probably more idiomatic for TeX than for LaTeX. Maybe loading etoolbox and using \ifnumequal{\value{section}}{0}{\thechapter}{\thesection} instead might've been better in that sense.)